# Keras shape: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tf.keras

I am working on CNN for image classification. Since I am a beginner I stuck at a place and I dont know how to resolve this issue. 
My `train_datagen`, `train_generator, validation_generator` like this;

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        validation_split=0.2) # set validation split

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"path_to_the_train_dir",
    target_size=(128, 128),
    class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    subset='training' # set as training data
)

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"path_to_the_train_dir", # same directory as training data
    target_size=(128, 128),
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='validation') # set as validation data
```

If I want to see the shape of the image from `train_generator`, I must do the following according to the book of `Francois Chollet`,

```
for data_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
    print(data_batch.shape())
```

But I get the following error when I follow the book;

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oh this is quite common. data_batch.shape; get rid of the parentheses after shape. Shape is an attribute of the object, not a method. So you cannot call it.

Answer (score 0):

remove the parentheses after shape.

```
for data_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
    print(data_batch.shape)
```